# Laravel FileSystem create CloudFront signed URL

Tags: laravel, amazon-cloudfront

I am working with CloudFront to serve content from S3.

WIth S3 only

```
Storage::disk('s3')->url($image_path); // return a normal s3 url - correct


Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($image_path, now()->addMinutes(30)) // return S3 signed url - correct
```

With CloudFront (Restrict Bucket Access is on, Restrict Viewer Access is on Use Signed URLs or Signed Cookies)

```
Storage::disk('s3')->url($image_path); // return a normal CloudFront url - correct

Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($image_path, now()->addMinutes(30)) // return S3 signed url - incorrect . I expect CloudFront signed url
```

This is my config for filesystem

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('S3_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('S3_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('S3_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('S3_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('CLOUDFRONT_URL'),
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep. for comment.

S3 `url` is for temp signing to S3 endpoint. Laravel by itself does not have ability to sign cloudfront URLs.

I found this package that can do that.

https://github.com/dreamonkey/laravel-cloudfront-url-signer